# String.Format with 2 parameters and ClientID

Tags: c#, asp.net

String.Format with 2 parameters (ID Database and ClientID)

I would like that result, was

```
<a id="ctl00" onclick="OpenModal(704520,'asdf')">
    <img id="crico" src="../online/img_admin/icon_hist.gif" />
</a>
```

**How to do?**

---

I'm trying so:

```
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" 
onclick='<%# String.Format("OpenModal({0},{1})", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"), (Image)GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID) ) %>' >
      <asp:Image ID="img_Historico" runat="server" />
    </asp:HyperLink>
```

so basically is:

```
OpenModal(Id_do_DataBase, 'ClientID of image')
```

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image'

---

Not working my code, so I asked here.

I also tried:  `onclick='<%# String.Format("AbreModal({0},{1})",   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"), img_Historico.ClientID )`

nothing works! :(

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Consider rewording your question... as a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
((Image)GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico")).ClientID
```

Also, if your data binding expression is so complex, then you should refactor it into a  property or method:

```
protected string ImgHistoricoClientID
{
    get {return ((Image)GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico")).ClientID;}
}
```

Databinding expression:

```
onclick='<%# String.Format("OpenModal({0},{1})", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"), ImgHistoricoClientID) ) %>' >
```

In fact, I would use the `ItemDataBound` event of the GridView to set the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this line:

```
(Image)GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID
```

ClientID is a string and you are casting it to an image. It should be:

```
GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID
```

To make it clearer this would also work (with an unnessisary cast)

```
((Image)GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico")).ClientID
```

Comment: okay. I did .. really is not an image
however:
GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID 
I get the error: The server tag is not well formed.

 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4"  runat="server" 
                             onclick='<%# String.Format("AbreModal({0},'{1}')",   DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "intid"),GridView1.FindControl("img_Historico").ClientID ) %>' >